# In CodeIgniter, Can we use Database Transactions like this?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, Are we also allowed to use "Active Record Class" like this?

```
<?php
$data_balance = array(
 'balance' => $newbalance
);
$data_transaction = array(
 'amount' => $amount,
 'user' => $user
);

$this->db->trans_start();
 // This is an "Insert" query for a table
 $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
 $this->db->insert('financial_transactions', $data_transaction);
 // This is an "Update" query for another table
 $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
 $this->db->update('financial_balances', $data_balance);
$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
    // Do stuff if failed 
}
?>
```

Note that i use $this->db-> for both queries, so i don't know if the success result of first one is actually cleared to check the second one?

Is this going to work? can i trust that this will make either both queries to success or neither of them (i don't want one to success and one to fail)

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html):

> By default CodeIgniter runs all transactions in Strict Mode. When strict mode is enabled, if you are running multiple groups of transactions, if one group fails all groups will be rolled back. If strict mode is disabled, each group is treated independently, meaning a failure of one group will not affect any others.